# How can I make a message into a blocks for NTRU?

Tags: public-key, ntru

I have more bits than the degree of the NTRU polynomial.

For example: $x^{11}-1$
message: `Hello` (I am using ascii, 8 bits for 1 symbol)
got: `0100100001100101011011000110110001101111`.

How should I split up message into blocks? Please answer with example.

Comment: You should use hybrid encryption, and NTRU parameters giving you a wide intermediary key.

Comment: I suppose the responses to [How can I use asymmetric encryption, such as RSA, to encrypt an arbitrary length of plaintext?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-can-i-use-asymmetric-encryption-such-as-rsa-to-encrypt-an-arbitrary-length) apply here just as well.